# Any documentation for Win32 ShellEx StorageHandler?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-explorer

I'm currently poking around with a new archive format and was interested in implementing a shell extension like the native Zip support that Windows XP has.

This appears to be done by registering a shell extension that implements a `StorageHandler`.  Problem is that according to MSDN, this handler doesn't exist.  I've tried Googling various resources, but haven't been able to find anything.

Is there *any* documentation for this anywhere, or is this just another case of Microsoft refusing to share the fun toys with the rest of us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you might find [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/msf3.aspx) helpful. It's one of a [short series](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=773600).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about StorageHandler. what you are trying to make is a shall namespace extenstion. Look up IShellFolder for a starting point.